# Build ElasticSearch BoolQuery By Using Conditional Statements With Java Api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have some queries on my code very similars. I want to shorten and clean my code building a generic `boolQuery` by using conditional statements. These are my methods:

```
private SearchRequestBuilder createSearchRequestInRangeForGroupId( String groupId,Date rangeStart,Date rangeEnd) {
          ...
          .setQuery(filteredQuery(
                    boolQuery()
                          .must(matchQuery(FIELD_GROUP_NAME, groupId)),
                          rangeFilter(FIELD_TIMESTAMP).gte(rangeStart.getTime()).lte(rangeEnd.getTime())))
          ...         
    }

private SearchRequestBuilder createSearchRequestInRangeForGender( String gender,Date rangeStart,Date rangeEnd) {
          ...
          .setQuery(filteredQuery(
                    boolQuery()
                          .must(matchQuery(FIELD_GENDER, gender)),
                          rangeFilter(FIELD_TIMESTAMP).gte(rangeStart.getTime()).lte(rangeEnd.getTime())))
          ...
    }

private SearchRequestBuilder createSearchRequestInRangeForGroupIdAndGender( String groupId,String gender,Date rangeStart,Date rangeEnd) {
          ...
          .setQuery(filteredQuery(
                    boolQuery()
                          .must(matchQuery(FIELD_GROUP_NAME, groupId))
                          .must(matchQuery(FIELD_GENDER, gender)),
                          rangeFilter(FIELD_TIMESTAMP).gte(rangeStart.getTime()).lte(rangeEnd.getTime())))
          ....

        return searchRequestBuilder;
    }
```

I want to make a `boolQuery` builder like this:

```
private SearchRequestBuilder createSearchRequestInRange( String groupId,String gender,Date rangeStart,Date rangeEnd) {
        ...
        .setQuery(filteredQuery(
                  buildBoolQuery(groupId,gender),
                  rangeFilter(FIELD_TIMESTAMP).gte(rangeStart.getTime()).lte(rangeEnd.getTime())))
        ...
    }



private QueryBuilder buildBoolQuery(String groupId, String gender){
        QueryBuilder boolQuery = boolQuery();

       if(groupId!=null && !groupId.isEmpty())
            boolQuery = boolQuery.must(matchQuery(FIELD_GROUP_NAME, groupId))
       }
       if(gender!=null && !gender.isEmpty())
            boolQuery = boolQuery.must(matchQuery(FIELD_GENDER, gender))
       }
       return boolQuery;
}
```

I've tried to do this but It's not possible. Is there any way to do this? 
Thanks you.

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not possible*? We do it in a somewhat similar way and it works just fine. Do you have any error or could you describe how the result differs from what you expect it to be?

Comment: I say that It's not possible because when I try to do `boolQuery.must(...)` boolQuery have not a method call `must()` . I think as you about I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I see. That's probably because your boolQuery is of type *QueryBuilder*. You probably need to use *BoolQueryBuilder* as in `BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();`

Comment: You're right! Post it as answer to accept. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because your boolQuery is of type QueryBuilder. You probably need to use BoolQueryBuilder as in `BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();`